# SQL filter turns my DBGrid into a blank table

Tags: sql, database, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to write a piece of code that would take the user's input if the default values have changed and put it in a SQL statement.

```
procedure TfrmHotels.btnFilterClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    iTest, iErrorCode, iMinStars, iMaxStars, iMinCost, iMaxCost: Integer;

begin
//This is the first thing the SQL does, by filtering the entire database to show all the hotels in the area the user has selected
  with dmCoAdventure do
    begin

      qryCoAdventure.SQL.Clear;
      qryCoAdventure.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Hotels WHERE TownName = ' + QuotedStr(frmTowns.sTown));
      qryCoAdventure.Open;

    end;
  //If the value changes
  if (spnMinStars.Value <> 0) OR (spnMaxStars.Value <> 0) then
    begin

      if spnMinStars.Value > spnMaxStars.Value then
        begin

          ShowMessage('Min Stars can''t be higher the Max Stars.');
          Exit;

        end
      else
        begin

          iMinStars:= spnMinStars.Value;
          iMaxStars:= spnMaxStars.Value;

          with dmCoAdventure do
            begin
             //Adds the filter
              qryCoAdventure.SQL.Add('AND Stars BETWEEN ' + IntToStr(iMinStars) + ' AND ' + IntToStr(iMaxStars));

              //ShowMessage('AND Stars BETWEEN ' + IntToStr(iMinStars) + ' AND ' + IntToStr(iMaxStars));

            end;

        end;

    end;
 //If the value changes
  if (edtMinCost.Text <> '') AND (edtMaxCost.Text <> '') then
    begin
     //Test that the min value is less than the max value
      if edtMinCost.Text > edtMaxCost.Text then
        begin

          ShowMessage('Min Cost can''t be more then Max Cost.');
          Exit;

        end
      else
        begin
       //Validate that it can change to an integer
          Val(edtMinCost.Text,iTest,iErrorCode);

          if iErrorCode = 0 then
            begin

              Val(edtMaxCost.Text,iTest,iErrorCode);

              if iErrorCode = 0 then
                begin

                  iMinCost:= StrToInt(edtMinCost.Text);
                  iMaxCost:= StrToInt(edtMaxCost.Text);

                  with dmCoAdventure do
                    begin
                        //Adds the filter
                      qryCoAdventure.SQL.Add('AND CostPNight BETWEEN ' + IntToStr(iMinCost) + ' AND ' + IntToStr(iMaxCost));

                    end;

                end
              else
                begin

                  ShowMessage('Min and Max values should both be numbers.');

                end;

            end
          else
            begin

              ShowMessage('Min and Max values should both be numbers.');

            end;

        end;

    end;

end;
```

At the moment when I add the min and max stars filter or even the cost filter the grid goes blank and doesn't display any data. I have tried to change the 'between' out for just the '<' or '>' operators and I still receive the same effect. My thinking was that it might be something to do with the way the SQL is set up, but I am not knowledgeable enough to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Your way of dealing with numeric columns in your Sql is wrong.  Taking the min and max costs as an example, if these columns are numeric, you shouldn't be using the QuotedStr around the TEdits' contents because you don't specify string values - use FloatToStr instead.  More generally, it is a thoroughly bad idea to construct Sql expressions by concatenating strings as you are now for a variety of reasons, not least exposure to Sql injection exploits and syntactic errors.  Instead, read up on parameterised queries and use those instead..

Comment: what I could find it seems that parameterized queries "removes" the use for the WHERE parameters. The project I am working on is a finals task that requires us to set the queries in this way. I have removed the QuotedStr as suggested, but I still get the same result. I've also displayed the querie in a ShowMessage to see what is displayed and it seems to look fine. I also tried to add the quarie (AND Stars BETWEEN 1 AND 4) to the onShow event of the form, this worked.

Comment: Well, you need to systematically debug your problem.  Remove all the conditions from your WHERE clause and then add them back one-by-one until you identify what's causing the empty result set..  Then fix it.

Comment: It happens when I add a second filter, ex. the stars or cost. I have tried hardcoding it, that works, but reading in the values form a variable it seems to cause the empty result.

Comment: Then just use the IDE's expression evaluator (F7) to see what's different when you do it the two ways.  If you get different results, the queries MUST be different.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the drive link to the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ssIBYjCmrhnSG-eKJmTNsD2q6-s2rEH1

The filter is in Hotels_u.

Comment: Sorry, we don't access external sources on SO.  You will need to debug this yourself.  Start by assigning the text of the query created one way to one string variable S1 and the other text to a second string variable S2.  Then add code to execute `S1 = S2` and see whether it returns true or false (it will return false) and dump the contents of the two variables to a visual container such as a TMemo so you can compare them on-screen.

Comment: All good. Both strings match.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "good" -if 2 identical strings produce different results, that's bad.  The most likely cause would be that you are getting memory corruption from a dangling pointer or similar.  Sorry, you are going to have to simplify your code down to the absolute minimun and seeing if you can make it work.  If it's any comfort I have never known two identical queries return different results on the same data.

Comment: All good on the external sources. This is not the first time that this has happened to me. I have had the same problem in a lot of other projects but set it off since it was not important that the user sees the table. I'll simplify it tomorrow. For now, I need to focus on a test.

Comment: As @MartynA says, it's impossible for two identical queries to return different values from the same data. If they're not returning the same values, then either one query is different from the other or they're looking at different data.

Comment: I understand that, but then how is it possible that a hardcoded string and the string retrieved from the two spin edits are the same? I have posted the same question on a discord community that is mainly delphi programmers from around the world and they find the syntax to be correct, but get the same result, a black table. The table is filtered, but doesn't display the data.

Comment: If you're getting no error and the DBGrid is empty, then no rows were returned by the query. Stop concatenating the SQL, use a parameterized query so that you can read the darn thing, and then come back and post both the code from your rewritten procedure, the hard-coded SQL with values you're testing against, and we might be able to help. Claiming you're getting different output from identical queries and identical values repeatedly (which is impossible) isn't going to get you an answer. Stop having conversations in the comments and [edit] the question to provide something we can work with.

Comment: Also, to reply to a comment from someone, use their name preceeded by an @ sign (as I did in my comment referencing MartynA in my first comment to you) so they know about it. Lucky for you, I just happened to stop by to see if you had done anything to improve your post so that I could try to help. It worked before because the only comment from anyone but you was by the same person, so they got a notification; once a third person joined the coments, those notifications stop because the site doesn't know who to notify.

Comment: I just read your code more carefully that is building the SQL, and I'd be willing to bet that the code you've assembled is wrong, and that makes it not identical to the query with the hard-coded values you're comparing against. I think instead that your throwing around all of the `IntToStr` and `QuotedStr`  is producing an erroneous value for one of the parameters you're passing the query and therefore it's producing no rows and causing the empty DBGrid. The code doesn't include anywhere you're opening the query, but if you're unwilling to rewrite the procedure at least add a call to...

Comment: `ShowMessage(qryCoAdventure.SQL.Text);` just before you do so and carefully inspect the SQL you've constructed.

Comment: @Ken White. Thank you for the tips, I am pretty new to StackOverflow and I appreciate it. I have been looking at parameterized query ever since @MartynA suggested it, but I simply don't understand it yet to even begin to use it, but I am still reading up on it. I am trying my best to give you all the information, I just don't know that much. I have only been using delphi for a bout a year now and delphi is my first programming experience.  With the `ShowMessage(qryCoAdventure.SQL.Text);` I can't see anything wrong with it, it looks the same as the one that is hardcoded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237979/62576 contains an example of a SQL statement with parameters, as well as an example of how to use it. With regards to the `ShowMessage`, either you missed something that makes them different OR (again) you're not looking at the same data. You don't say what DBMS you're using, but if you really insist that the same **identical** SQL statements and the same **exact** data is producing different output, you should contact the people who write that DBMS and file a bug report, because it would be serious enough to make their product unuseable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Ken White's comments are correct.  As you are obviously struggling with how to put
what we've said into practice, here is a sample project that is as simple
as possible which shows how to correctly use parameters in a Sql query.  To follow it:

1. Create a new Delphi VCL project and add to its form

   - AdoConnection1 whose ConnectionString is set to connect to your Sql server
   - AdoQuery1 which uses AdoConnection1
   - DataSource1 with its DataSet property set to AdoQuery1
   - DBGrid1 whose DataSource property is set to DataSource1
   - Two buttons, named btnCreateTable and btnApplyFilter with event handlers as shown in the code below.
2. Edit the project's form to include the code shown below.
3. Compile and run the project.
4. Click btnCreateTable.  The Sql it executes is written for Microsft Sql Server
   so may not work 100% correctly if you are using a different server type.  If either
   of the sQl statements produces an exception, edit the sCreateTable and/or
   sInsertRows constants until both execute correctly.  If that is too much trouble,
   simply create the Hotels table manually and insert the rows manually as well.

   Once you have the Hotels table with the data rows in it ...
5. Click btnApplyFilter
6. The grid should display only rows 3 and 4.  If it doesn't, you've done
   something wrong, so check everything, fix any mistakes and try again.

Now, study the code in procedure TForm1.ApplyFilter very carefully.

The FilterSql constant specifies a parameterised Sql query, the parameters being
the required minimum and maximum numbers of stars:  the :Min and :Max are these
parameters.

Once the FilterSql has been supplied to AdoQuery1, the code sets AdoQuery1.Prepared to True;
what this does is to send the query to the Sql server to parse it and set up a
the query for execution; what it doesn't do is actually execute the query.
The query the server prepares includes the Min and Max values as "placeholders"
and the server expects to be told the values of these parameters before it actually
executes the query. That's what the lines

```
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Min').Value := MinStars;
AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Max').Value := MaxStars;
```

Finally, the call to

```
AdoQuery1.Open
```

tells the server to actually execute the query and, once the server has, AdoQuery1
reads the results from the server and displays them in the grid.

Code

```
const
  sCreateTable = 'create table Hotels(ID Int primary key, Name NVarChar(20), Stars int)';

  sInsertRows =  'insert Hotels(ID, Name, Stars) values(1, ''One'', 1)'
  +  ' insert Hotels(ID, Name, Stars) values(2, ''Two'', 5)'
  +  ' insert Hotels(ID, Name, Stars) values(3, ''Three'', 3)'
  +  ' insert Hotels(ID, Name, Stars) values(4, ''Four'', 2)';

procedure TForm1.ApplyFilter(MinStars, MaxStars : Integer);
const
  FilterSql = 'select * from Hotels where Stars between :Min and :Max';
begin
  if AdoQuery1.Active then
    AdoQuery1.Close;

  AdoQuery1.Sql.Text := FilterSql;
  AdoQuery1.Prepared := True;
  AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Min').Value := MinStars;
  AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Max').Value := MaxStars;

  AdoQuery1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnApplyFilterClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ApplyFilter(2, 3);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnCreateTableClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoConnection1.Execute(sCreateTable);
  AdoConnection1.Execute(sInsertRows);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @MartynA. It was a library corruption issue the entire time, after updating the IDE it fixed the problem, but I will still be using the parameterized query since I've realized that it is a much safer bet.